# one statement to pull all the data with same attribute name from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My ajax call returns this :(there are two images and the number of images may vary)

```html
[{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/1.png"},

{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/completionist.png"}]
```

I am able to display the images in my UI as follows :

```html
if (counter<=0){
 $('#imagesofBadges').append('<img src="'  + data[0].BadgeImage + '"/>');
 $('#imagesofBadges').append('<img src="'  + data[1].BadgeImage + '"/>');
counter++;
}
```

**Problem :**
**The point is I dont want to use two append statements as the no of images returned by the ajax call may vary.It will depend on the condition set to pull the images from DB.The images are pulled from the same column name "BadgeImage" as can be seen in the ajax data.**

The code I tried :

```html
var $img = $('<img src="'  + data[0].BadgeImage + '"/>'); // create the image
$img.addClass('badge-image'); // add the class .badge-image to it
$('#imagesofBadges').append($img); // append it

$('#imagesofBadges .badge-image'); // will fetch all the elements that have the class .badge-image that are inside #imagesofBadges.
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```html
 $('#imagesofBadges').empty();
 $.each(data, function(index, value) {
   //Your code
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code using .each function

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = '[{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/1.png"}, {"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/completionist.png"},{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/2.png"},{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/3.png"}]';
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            var $img = $('<img class="badge-image" src="'  + data[index].BadgeImage + '"/>'); // create the image
            $('#imagesofBadges').append($img); // append it
        });

        $('#imagesofBadges .badge-image').each(function () {
           alert($(this).attr('src'));
        }); // will fetch all the elements that have the class .badge-image that are inside #imagesofBadges.
    });
</script>
</head>

<div id="imagesofBadges">

</div>
```

Comment: u got it wrong.as I have said the number of images from the ajax call may vary.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't get your requirement correctly. My answer is for displaying (append) n number of images dynamically in html using script. the data array may contain n number of images.

Comment: You will get the data array from ajax.

Comment: plz look at the above codes in my question.I believe u are very close to the solution.

Comment: plz try my code. it will work without repeating data calls like data[0] data[1]. I have used .each() function to iterate the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133953/discussion-between-mith-and-jane).

Answer (score 1):

Actually,I do not get your point.Maybe you can try this!

```
var data = [
    {"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/1.png"},
    {"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/completionist.png"}];
var dom = data.map(function (value) {
    return '<img src="'  + value.BadgeImage + '"/>';
})
$('#imagesofBadges').append(dom.join(''));
```